# std::sting ? string does not name a type error

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I got these 2 files for now and anytime I want to compile I get the error

> `string` does not name a type

in `Bestellung.h` on the line with `std::string name;`.
Why?

#### main.cpp

```
#include "Bestellung.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Bestellung();
    cout << Bestellung{"maki"} << endl;// [maki,10€]
}
```

#### Bestellung.cpp

```
#include "Bestellung.h"

Bestellung(string bestellV, double preisV = 10){
    name = "bestell V";
    preis = "preis V";
};
string get_name const(Bestellung v) {
    return Bestellung.name;
};
double get_preis const(Bestellung v){
    return Bestellung.preis;
};
ostream& print(ostream&) const {
};
```

#### Bestellung.h

```
#ifndef BESTELLUNG_H
#define BESTELLUNG_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Bestellung{
    std::string name;
    std::double preis;
public:
    Bestellung(string, double = 10);
    string get_name const {
    };
    double get_preis const {
    };
    ostream& print(ostream&) const {
    };
};
#endif
```

Comment: several places in "bestellung.h" you fail to use `std::` where required

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a namespace qualifier. You have:

```
Bestellung(string,double=10);
```

You should have:

```
Bestellung(std::string,double=10);
```

You also have:

```
string get_name const {
```

You should have:

```
std::string get_name const {
```

If you don't want to specify the `std` namespace every time you use a string, you can do this near the beginning:

```
using std::string;
```

Doing that in header files is bad practice though, so I would just use the full qualifications like I said to first.
After correcting this error, you need to do the same thing to that `ostream` you have too.

Read more about namespaces [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

Comment: I still get the error before i even reach there (Bestellung(std::string,double=10), for some reason i get said error message line above at     std::string name; I slowly get the feeling my compiler is malfunctioning